# Why does Kashiwara define $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ rather than $\mathbb{C}(q)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

When defining crystal bases, why do we typically view $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ rather than $\mathbb{C}(q)$? In Kashiwara's original paper introducing crystal bases, he defines quantum groups over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$, and most sources seem to do the same. But for example in [Crystal bases and categorifications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.00114) by Kashiwara he defined them over $\mathbb{C}(q)$, which feels more natural to me. Does this change the theory at all, or is it just a random convention?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ is slightly more general, right?

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I guess I was expecting it to have something to do with the fact that we're taking a crystal basis, since the convention seems more ubiquitous in that context. But that could just be a knock on effect of Kashiwara defining it that way originally. Thanks!

Comment: Working over $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ may also have computational advantages: for computers it's much easier to keep track of rational numbers than complex numbers, where precision issues may play a role.

Comment: This makes me wonder: does the theory of highest weight modules of Kac-Moody algebras, for example the character formula of $L(\Lambda)$ hold in general over $\mathbb{Q}$?